# Calculating order of an intersection of a subgroup of order $p^a$ and a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am self-studying abstract algebra using Dummit and Foote.  One of the exercises, which should in theory be solvable using nothing more than the isomorphism theorems, runs as follows:

Let $p$ be a prime and let $G$ be a group of order $p^am$, where $p$ does not divide $m$.  Assume $P$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^a$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p^bn$ where $p$ does not divide $n$.  Prove that $|P \cap N| = p^b$ and $|PN/N| = p^{a-b}$.

By Lagrange's Theorem, we know that $|P \cap N|$ divides both $|P|$ and $|N|$; we therefore see that $|P \cap N| = p^k$ for some positive integer $k$ with $k \leq a$ and $k \leq b$.  As far as I can see, though, that's as much as we have:  I don't see why $k$ has to be $b$, rather than some integer between $0$ and $b-1$.

(Note that if we accept that $n = b$, the fact that $|PN/N| = p^{a - b}$ follows directly from the Second Isomorphism theorem.  So that part of the exercise doesn't worry me.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $N$ is normal, $PN$ is a subgroup, and you may apply the formula $$|P\cap N|\cdot |PN|={|P|\cdot |N|}=p^{a+b}n$$
Now

- $|P\cap N|\leq p^b$ by Lagrange,
- $|PN|\leq \gcd(p^{a+b}n,|G|)=p^an$.

Therefore both inequalities above are equalities.

---

Note that this property can be expressed in terms of Sylow subgroups: the intersection between a Sylow subgroup and a normal subgroup $N$ is a Sylow subgroup of $N$.